# What is NXT's "lessor"?

Tags: development, api, nxt, terminology

While reading [NXT's API wiki page](http://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Nxt_API) I came across something called a "[lessor](http://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Nxt_API#Get_Account_Lessors)", but I can't find its definition anywhere. What is a lessor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lessor, in general, is a person who leases a property to another.

NXT allows you to ["lease" your forging ability to someone else.](http://wiki.nxtcrypto.org/wiki/Account_Leasing)

So `getAccountLessors` gets a list of people who have leased their forging power to your account.